# Rails 3 validates_format_of not working for a simple regex

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, validation

Having trouble getting a simple validation to work in Rails 3, even though [the regex works fine](http://rubular.com/r/929DCyA2V8). Even with a valid format, the validation fails.

Model:

```
validates_format_of :start,
  with:    /\A[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4}\z/,
  message: "Invalid date format"
```

Assertion:

```
Event.new(start: "12/10/2010").valid?.should eq(true)
```

That assertion is failing because `valid?` returns `false`.

What am I missing?

Comment: maybe something else in the new event is causing event to be not valid?

Comment: Is this YAML or normal ruby? If yaml, what're doing the commas at the end of line?

Comment: @Rekin: that is Ruby 1.9 Hash Syntax: http://blog.peepcode.com/tutorials/2011/rip-ruby-hash-rocket-syntax

Comment: @chipotle_warrior: have a look at `e = Event.new(start: "12/10/2010"); e.valid?; e.errors`

Comment: What datatype does the start column have? Is it a normal VARCHAR or a DATE?

Comment: @RobinBrouwer, thanks! The column is a DATE. Figured that if I instantiated the object what that attribute as a string, it would be up to me to convert it to a date. Nope. Rails is a step ahead of me and converts it to a date at instantiation, which explains why the regex doesn't match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regex fails because `start` is a `Date` type, and when the object is instantiated with a string, ActiveRecord automagically converts it to a `Date`. By the time the validator gets ahold of it, it's no longer a string, so there's no match.